# Nested dropdown in markdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, markdown, dropdown, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I want to nest dropdown menus in the following Markdown code but the innermost dropdowns are not "inside" the outermost one. That is, they don't disappear when I click the dropdown button.

```html
<details>
<summary> Year 1 (2021 - 2022) <summary>
  
  <details>
  <summary> Refreshers </summary>
  <ul>
    <li> Algorithmics </li>
    <li> Basic tools </li>
  </ul>
  </details>

  <details>
  <summary> Semester 1 </summary>
  <ul>
    <li> Data Visualization </li>
    <li> Ethics </li>
  </ul>
  </details>
  
</details>
```

Is there a way to do what I want?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Markdown—you just have a typo. You are opening a second `<summary>` tag instead of closing the first one:

```html
<details>
<summary> Year 1 (2021 - 2022) </summary>
<!--                            ^ this / is missing -->
...  
</details>
```